# TTreeview Select Item and Level?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7

I have a TTreeView

I add two levels of items to

```
Test 1 Parent  
  Test 1 Child  
Test 2 Parent  
  Test 2 Child A  
  Test 2 Child B  
  Test 2 Child C
```

I am trying to enable and disable my Add, Edit, and Delete buttons based on what level is selected

Example:

```
procedure TfrmMain.UpdateBtns;  
begin  
btnEditParent.Enabled:= (treeview.Focused ) AND (treeview.Selected <> nil);     btnDeleteParent.Enabled:= (treeview.Focused ) AND (treeview.Selected <> nil);  
btnAddChild.Enabled:= (treeview.Focused ) AND (treeview.Selected <> nil);  
btnEditChild.Enabled:= (treeview.Focused ) AND (treeview.Selected <> nil);  
btnDeleteChild.Enabled:= (treeview.Focused ) AND (treeview.Selected <> nil);  
end;
```

how do i take the levels into consideration?

Comment: How would you *like* to take levels into consideration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [`TTreeNode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TTreeNode) object  has a [`Level`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ComCtrls.TTreeNode.Level) property

```
var
 Node : TTreeNode;
begin
 Node:=TreeView1.Selected;
 //Node.Level //The first Level is 0

end;
```

you can rewrite your code in this way

```
    var
     Node : TTreeNode;
    begin
     Node:=TreeView.Selected;
     if Node<>nil then
     begin
      btnEditParent.Enabled  := (Node.Level=0);
      btnDeleteParent.Enabled:= (Node.Level=0);
      btnAddChild.Enabled    := (Node.Level=0);
      btnEditChild.Enabled   := (Node.Level>0);
      btnDeleteChild.Enabled := (Node.Level>0);
     end;
    end;
```